# lambda - this.create is not a function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

using AWS Lambda, I get a new type of error for something that has worked for a long time.

In my code I have something like:

```
import { load as loadCache, Cache } from 'flat-cache';


...
export class CacheStore {
  cache: Cache;

  constructor() {
    if(process.env.stageName != 'Dev'){
      this.cache = loadCache(CACHE_ID, '/cache');
    } else {
      this.cache = loadCache(CACHE_ID);
    }
  }
...
```

The flat-cache dependency gets bundled up together with the above source code into index.js:

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Alias for create. Should be considered depreacted. Will be removed in next releases
   *
   * @method load
   * @param docId {String} the id of the cache, would also be used as the name of the file cache
   * @param [cacheDir] {String} directory for the cache entry
   * @returns {cache} cache instance
   */
  load: function (docId, cacheDir) {
    return this.create(docId, cacheDir); // <- This is the error line
  },

  /**
   * Load a cache identified by the given Id. If the element does not exists, then initialize an empty
   * cache storage.
   *
   * @method create
   * @param docId {String} the id of the cache, would also be used as the name of the file cache
   * @param [cacheDir] {String} directory for the cache entry
   * @returns {cache} cache instance
   */
  create: function (docId, cacheDir) {
    var obj = Object.create(cache);
    obj.load(docId, cacheDir);
    return obj;
  },
```

Up until recently, this worked well. Now it returns an error message saying:
`this.create is not a function` and highlighting the line number leading to the above line.

When I replace loadCache/load with create, it works again.
As you can see above, load, simply invokes create.

Trying out some local tests like these, everything works perfectly. Therefore the big question mark why it would not work in a AWS lambda?

```
(() => {
    console.log('starting')
})();

module.exports = {
    load: function (name) {
        return this.create(name)
    },

    create: function(name) {
        console.log(name);
        return name + ' yelled'
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are the lambda node version and the bundled target runtime matching? What target are you building for?

Comment: target: 'node'. As for the node versions, they weren't matching indeed. Was built on 16 but using 14 in the lambda itself. After upgrading the lambda to 16, nothing changed (same crash, same error).